# Axios POST request - setting headers

Tags: javascript, forms, post, axios, request-headers

I am trying to mimic a form submit with an Axios post request - to be more precise, I am trying to turn this:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://testpaymentgateway...">     
<input type="text" name="amount" value="1000"/>     
<input type="submit" text="submit"/>     
</form>
```

into something like this:

```
let paymentData = new FormData();

paymentData.append('amount','1000');

axios.post('https://testpaymentgateway...', paymentData, {     
headers: {      
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate'     
}     
})     
.then(function (response) {     
console.log(response);     
})     
.catch(function (response) {     
console.log(response);     
});
```

The first example with manually submitting the form works ok, while the axios post request returns a CORS error. I have compared the two requests and found that some of the headers are different, however, the axios request doesn't seem to set the headers I'm trying to set, the content-type is always "multipart/form-data" and sec-fetch-mode is always "cors". I have tried different ways of setting the headers object, but none of them are working. Any idea why this might be happening?